# Print CSS make text bold in Bootstrap col-md-6

Tags: html, css

I want to style the font/text to bold to text inside the

```
    col-md-6 label-wrapper
```

I tried some css styling but does not affect the current font of my webpage when printing

```
    .col-md-6{
           display: relative;
        }
        .col-md-6 label-wrapper{
           font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Also I want to display it horizontaly in print, something like

```
    purchase order: 34567
    name: abcd
    street: ca
    qty: ty
```

Currently, when I print the selected html content using Javascript print function, the output looks like this

```
   purchase order:
   34567
   name:
   abcd
   qty:
   67
```

My content

```
   <div class="col-md-4 order-column prod-wrapper">
      <h3 class="vo-title"> Order Details </h3>
      <div class="prod-row vo-content">
          <div class="col-md-6 label-wrapper"> Purchase Order #: </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 "> <?php echo $order[0]['po_number']; ?></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with the js pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 order-column prod-wrapper">
      <h3 class="vo-title"> Order Details </h3>
      <div class="prod-row vo-content">
          <div class="col-md-6 label-wrapper"> Purchase Order #: </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 result ">3567</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
 .col-md-6{
           display: relative;
        }
        .label-wrapper{
           font-weight: bold !important;
        }
        .col-md-6 {
          display: inline;
        }
```

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/knmxrccq/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, because it didn't work. I saw it *should* work, and then thought it could depend on the font, which it does. Switching from my fancy font to a more standard one (Arial) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `font-weight:bold !important;` or `font-weight:600;`

If that doesn't work, `font-weight: 600 !important;`

!important overrides the previous statement.

OR, if that doesn't work, play around with the .bold() function, or place the output between `<b></b>` or `<strong></strong>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

On you CSS you have:

```
  .col-md-6 label-wrapper{
           font-weight: bold;
        }
```

You forgot to set .(dot) on labe-wrapper (it's a class)

```
.col-md-6 .label-wrapper{
               font-weight: bold;
            }
```

To display both lines in the same line use on col-md-6

```
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess You need for the font problem to use

```
.label-wrapper
{
   font-weight: 600+ (<900) (!important if the style sheet is override by bootstrap)
}
```

And to get your element in one line you can use `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```css
.my-data {
    font-weight:bold !important;}
```

```html
<div class"col-md-6 my-data">Purchase Order#: 
    <span><?php echo echo $order[0]['po_number']; ?></span>
</div>
```